# How to display this categories in post?

Tags: wordpress

I have:

custom post type - "services"

custom taxonomy - "services_category".

And i have terms structure like this:

```
bmw
 - bmw e60/61
    - bmw 520d
       - Maintenance
               (Post: Maintenance bmw 520d)
       - Retrofitting
       - Repair
         - Engine repair
                 (Post: engine repair bmw 520d)
         - Automatic transmission repair
                 (Post: AT oil change bmw 520d)
    - bmw 530i
       - Maintenance
               (Post: Maintenance bmw 530i)
       - Retrofitting
       - Repair
         - Engine repair
                 (Post: engine repair bmw 530i)
         - Automatic transmission repair
                 (Post: AT oil change bmw 530i)
```

How to display a list of main categories of current model, in the post's sidebar? model i mean e.g bmw 520d, or bmw 530i, etc.

E.g:
in post "engine repair bmw 530i", display in sidebar links to: "Maintenance", "Retrofitting", "Repair" of bmw 530i

in post "engine repair bmw 520d", display in sidebar links to: "Maintenance", "Retrofitting", "Repair" of bmw 520d

i just want to display this categories in post's sidebar:
[image]

this is my code which works, but if here https://prnt.sc/v31jjw i choose other models, it will show the wrong links.

```
<?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'services_category', array('fields' => 'all'));

if(!empty($terms)) {
  $first_term = $terms[0];

  $items = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'services_category',
    'orderby'       => 'id', 
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => false, 
    'object_ids'    => null,
    'number'        => '', 
    'fields'        => 'all', 
    'count'         => false,
    'slug'          => '', 
    'parent'         => $first_term->term_id,
    'hierarchical'  => true, 
    'child_of'      => 0, 
    'get'           => '',
    'name__like'    => '',
  ));
  ?>
  <div class="col-xl-3">
    <aside class="services-aside">
      <nav class="services-aside__nav">
        <ul class="services-aside__list">
          <?php
          foreach( $items as $term ){
            $term_link = get_term_link($term);
            ?>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" class="services-aside__link">
                  <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                </a>
              </li>
            <?php
          }
          ?>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you can check category parent is 0 or not. all 0 value is the parent category

To show in the product loop.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if( $categories ){
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        if ( $category->parent < 1 ) {
            // Your code
        }
    }
}
```

To display in the sidebar.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'parent'   => 0
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: thanks for answer! But this code didn't work for me, i need to get model (bmw 520d) term_id, and then display first-level categories of this model. If the post belongs in bmw 530i, then display first-level categories of bmw 530i.

Comment: i could just use get_terms, and then pass the term_id of MODEL into 'parent' field, to get first-level categories, but main problem is, how to get the term_id of MODEL category, in which post belongs?

Comment: i just want to display this categories in post's sidebar -  https://prnt.sc/v2zf52

Comment: it's displaying category "Models", but i need to display certain cars's top level categories, not category with id of 0. https://prnt.sc/v31b0d Please read my question again if you don't understand. Anyway thanks for answering!